# Fails on reading a many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm building an exercise web API backend which connects to a MySQL database with courses and subjects. I'm using EntityFrameworkCore 7 to communicate with the database, with the code-first approach. For some reason my code fails to read a many-to-many relations table.

The database contains tables: `Courses`, `Subjects`, `Coursesubjects`.
A course can contain multiple subjects (eg. a Maths course can have subjects about functions, matrices, sets etc).
A subject can belong to multiple courses (eg. a functions subject can belong to Maths and Physics).
Hence the third table - `Coursesubjects` - contains the many-to-many relations between entities from the `Courses` and `Subjects` tables.

When I call the method to get all subjects related to a specific course, it fails without any error. Reading specific entities from `Courses` or `Subjects` works fine.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>> GetSubjectsForCourseAsync(string courseId)
{
    var data = await _dbContext.CourseSubjects.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseId)
                                       .Include(m => m.Subject)
                                       .Include(m => m.Course)
                                       .Select(s => new SubjectDto()
                                       {
                                           Id = s.Subject.Id,
                                           Title = s.Subject.Title,
                                           Description = s.Subject.Descrip,
                                       }).ToListAsync();
    return data;
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Method is ok, but you can remove `Includes`, they are not needed. Probably problem in other place which calls method `GetSubjectsForCourseAsync`.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails without any error"? Returning empty list? How about `var list = _dbContext.CourseSubjects.ToList();` and looking at the list if there is item with the desired `CourseId`? Also can we see the model classes and fluent configuration, to be sure that FKs/navigation properties are mapped correctly.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, how can I tell EF to also take the related subject and course if I don't use `Include()`?

Comment: Actually you don't load Course. `Select` shows what you load. Usually when you have `Select`, includes are ignored completely by EF Core.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, so how should I modify this code to get all subjects related to a course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was that my class was called `CourseSubjects` but the table for it in the database was called `Coursesubjects` and this caused the mismatch.

The solution was to wrap the code in the method within a try-catch block and then see the error message.

```
try
{
    data = await _dbContext.CourseSubjects.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseId)
                                   .Include(m => m.Subject)
                                   .Include(m => m.Course)
                                   .Select(s => new SubjectDto()
                                   {
                                       Id = s.Subject.Id,
                                       Title = s.Subject.Title,
                                       Description = s.Subject.Descrip,
                                   }).ToListAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```